# Next.js implantation - does it completely replace normal React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

If not the right place let me know and I'll delete.

In a normal project,
I'd separate the frontend (in this case, React) and the backend
(in this case, Node.js) to separate parts in my app.

I'm looking to create an app the will meet SEO needs, therefore I'll use Next.js for SSR.
What should my app look like? One chunk of beckend?
Is there any reason to create specific frontend components in normal React?

Comment: Nextjs is the meta-framework, what you will be writing is basically React. There are lot of good optimizations done already in nextjs, that help you out upfront. And yes a forum like a spectrum or discord may be the right place for this question.

Comment: Thank u. Can u link to spectrum? couldn't find the right one.

Comment: I think github is also a good place to get better clarity. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions